# Ruby get RSS feed won't get the latest feed

Tags: ruby, rss, sinatra

I have a problem parsing an RSS feed. 
When I do this:

```
  feed = getFeed("http://example.com/rss)
```

If the feed content changes it don't update.

If I do it like this:

```
feed = getFeed("http://example.com/rss?" + Random.rand(20).to_s)
```

It works most of the time but not always.

`getFeed()` is implemented like this:

```
def getFeed(url)
   rss_content = ""
   open(url) do |f|
      rss_content = f.read
   end
   return rss_content
end
```

I used this in Sinatra with Ruby 1.9.3, if this make a difference.
On my opinion somewhere it gets cached but I have no idea where.

Edit:
Okey after 1/2 day running on the server it works with out a problem.

Comment: This previous discussion might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389255/rss-feed-how-to-recommend-an-update-interval

Comment: not sure because this mean that open() check this, and i don't think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
feed = getFeed("http://example.com/rss?" + Random.rand(20).to_s)
```

implies the problem is with caching, but Ruby, OpenURI and Sinatra shouldn't be caching anything. Perhaps your code is running behind a caching device or app that is handling outgoing requests as well as incoming?

This isn't the fix, but your code can be streamlined greatly:

```
def getFeed(url)
  open(url).read
end
```